# scikit-learn intersphinx link / inventory object?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-sphinx

Has anyone successfully linked to scikit-learn with intersphinx. It's a sphinx project and it looks like it's hosted through github pages

`https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.github.io`

But so far I haven't been able to generate complete links in my sphinx project to land on scikit learn pages

currently using

`'sklearn': ('http://scikit-learn.org/stable' None)`

in my interspinx mapping, any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Can you provide examples of intersphinx links that you tried? Here is one that works for me: ``:any:`sklearn.base.BaseEstimator` ``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems from this [issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1615) linking this [PR](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/commit/b63fefe135638cc61d600580830978a89d5ef34c) that you should use:

```python
'sklearn': ('http://scikit-learn.org/stable',
            (None, './_intersphinx/sklearn-objects.inv'))
```

Note: not tested but interested in the result, please let me know if it works.

---

**EDIT:**

Seems that [sklearn-objects.inv](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/1f8c74f69e0f9e72c59f180b2fc96d311659c609/doc/source/_intersphinx/sklearn-objects.inv) is available from scikit-image repo for local intersphinx settings.
That's probably not the best solution, but maybe it can help for a start.

I assume you already tried to link directly to the [documentation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html) of scikit-learn or maybe to the [API page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html) of the project (but yet I ask, just in case...).
I am not sure what would be the appropriate page from what is indicated in Sphinx doc.

> A dictionary mapping unique identifiers to a tuple (target,
>   inventory). **Each target is the base URI of a foreign Sphinx
>   documentation set** and can be a local path or an HTTP URI. The
>   inventory indicates where the inventory file can be found: it can be
>   None (at the same location as the base URI) or another local or HTTP
>   URI.

Otherwise there is also [`sphobjinv`](http://sphinx-objectsinv-encoderdecoder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that could help to build a custom intersphinx object.inv, but I had no time to test it yet.

Comment: I tired that as well and saw 

`Running Sphinx v1.6.3
loading pickled environment... done
loading intersphinx inventory from ./_intersphinx/sklearn-objects.inv...
WARNING: intersphinx inventory './_intersphinx/sklearn-objects.inv' not fetchable due to <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: `

so I don't think that's the answer, for that to work I think you need a local version of objects.inv, which I haven't been able to find (or I would just point intersphinx to that, I think? I'm not a sphinx expert but I've used it a fair bit

Any other thoughts would be great, thanks!

Comment: @MarkWeiss: edited with more ideas, hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks @ FabienP, unfortunately I already tried that, most of my experience with intersphinx is when finding the routing through how definitions are made (like some obj in the networkx inventory are registered through funcs even through they are classes, I think I ran into that with DiGraph. I'm not really sure how to find the inventory object. I also took a look at the github pages site but wasn't able to back anything out, I'll certainly post if I get this working, which should be possible!

Comment: @MarkWeiss: even with `sklearn-objects.inv` from scikit-image repo downloaded to your local dir? damn I though this would work at least... Please do not hesitate to post if you find anything, I'm highly interested!

Comment: I'm going with that thanks, it's for a shared project so having my conf file pull the inv obj is less than ideal but not a big deal, thanks for the help I appreciate it

Comment: Using https instead of http will ensure some security while downloading the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing comma in your intersphinx mapping:

```
'sklearn': ('http://scikit-learn.org/stable' None)
```

should be:

```
'sklearn': ('http://scikit-learn.org/stable', None),
```

I use trailing commas for my dict entries, but they are not required.

With that correction, I was able to use the entry that @mzjn provided in their comment to generate a link to scikit-learn's docs.

Comment: apologies for the  typo in the post, but my conf file is formatted correctly. Pulling and then linking the scikit image obj worked well for me, but that's not a great solution.

Comment: Then please provide an example of what you use for generating links to scikit-learn, any error or warning messages that appear, whether you also added `'sphinx.ext.intersphinx'` to your `extensions` configuration value in conf.py, and your version of Sphinx. It works for me on Sphinx 1.6 without the hack.

Comment: It works for me too without the hack (Sphinx 1.6.3).